# Xubuntu 10.04, I pressed the little door in the upper right of the screen

Tags: xubuntu

I just installed Xubuntu 10.04 and pressed the little door in the upper right corner of the screen. Now the GUI has disappeared.

The only thing I get is the blue background with the Trees and birds.

Left or Right mouse clicks do nothing.

The GUI does not reappear when I restart or shutdown.
The GUI does not appear if I choose xubuntu session or Xfce session.

Can someone explain to me how to get out of the twilight zone and back into Ubuntu?

Comment: It (should) bring up a menu asking if you wish to logout, shutdown, reboot, etc. The only thing that I can think of that you are seeing is the login manager, but I thought XFCE used gdm.